# Error loading model into tensorflowjs using loadGraphModel

Tags: javascript, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I trained a model in python with tensorflow keras, saved it with `model.save(...)`, converted it with tensorflow-converter and tried to load it into tensorflowjs using `tf.loadGraphModel("myurl")`. But I got an error on the webconsole saying: `TypeError: e.node is undefined` in `operation_mapper.ts:74:20`. The website can be found [here](https://jpcm_2019.gitlab.io/jpcm/MNIST.html) and my script [here](https://jpcm_2019.gitlab.io/jpcm/Javascript/MNISTScript.js).

Comment: Did you try tf.loadLayersModel?

Comment: Yes, I did, but the error I got using `loadLayersMode`l, but it only threw another, more confusing error: `Error: Axis 1,24 of input tensor should have a defined dimension but the layer received an input with shape [null,28,28,1]`. But if somebody know how to fix this error it will also be fine.